# jquery not adding the values to database, readystate=0, and status=0

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

My script does not seem to be working. Every time i try to use the form i've get the error with readystate=0, and status=0. Any help will be appreciated.
I've got the following form:

```
<form action="" method="post" >

    <input type="text" name="name" id="tekst"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="autor"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="Send" id="submit"/>

</form>
<div class="response"></div>
```

the values from input fields are then processed by the following code:

```
$("input#submit").click(function(){  
var id = $("input#submit").attr("name");
var autor =  $('input#autor').val();
var tresc = $('input#tekst').val();


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add_comment.php",
    data: 
    {id: id, 
    autor: autor, 
    tresc: tresc}, 
    success: function(data){
        $(".response").text(data);  
    },
   error:function(xhr,err){
    alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
    alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);

    }



});
});
```

Here is my add_comment.php:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$autor= $_POST['autor'];
$tresc = $_POST['tresc'];

if(isset($id) && isset($autor) && isset($tresc)){
include("db/connection.php");

$zapytanie= "INSERT INTO komentarze(id_ref, autor, tresc) values ('$id', '$autor', '$tresc')";
$wynik = $db->query($zapytanie);
echo "Added";
}else{
    echo "Problem";
}


?>
```

EDIT:
id_ref is not auto_increment field. The script is running on the localhost

Comment: What is id_ref in database. Is it auto_increment field? or just some other field?

Comment: Are you running it against an actual web server or are you trying to run it locally?

Comment: @raheelshan - it is not auto_increment field

Comment: @devnull69 it is running on the localhost

Comment: which means: A webserver on localhost or direct file access with no webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your form isn't correct...**name="name", class=".response"**??

```
<form action="" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="tekst" id="tekst"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="autor" id="autor"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="id" value="Send" id="submit"/>
</form>
<div class="response"></div>
```

Your PHP File should be"

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$autor= $_POST['autor'];
$tresc = $_POST['tekst'];

if(isset($id) && isset($autor) && isset($tresc)){
include("db/connection.php");

$zapytanie= "INSERT INTO komentarze(id_ref, autor, tresc) values ('$id', '$autor', '$tresc')";
$wynik = $db->query($zapytanie);
echo "Added";
}else{
    echo "Problem";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please don't forget to escape the user input, though!

Comment: @daan - i know, but this has to be taken care of by vincent himself, as he best knows the check conditions. Upvote to you for raising it though :)

Comment: @Pushpesh - thanks for your reply. However, the code still gives the same error. Could you also tell me why have you changed $_POST['tresc'] to $_POST['tekst']? Thank you

Comment: @vincent - i checked on my system and it works fine. Just take my html and php code, your js code is fine. I changed $_POST['tresc'] to $_POST['tekst'] because there is no such field in the html form with the name 'tresc'...the "name" attribute matters in php, not the id attribute.

Comment: Pushpesh, that's wrong, 'tresc' was correct. It has to match the keys on the data object passed to `.ajax`, not the field name.

Comment: @Pushpesh - the code is working!:) I think that it should be $_POST['tresc'], cause this is refering to the variable created in javascript. However the script is working, i have to change this statement  "if(isset($id) && isset($autor) && isset($tresc))"
and repair some mistakes you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="add_comment.php" method="post" >

<input type="text" name="tekst" id="tekst"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="autor" id="autor"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Send" id="submit"/>

</form>
```

And in php it should be like this

```
$id = $_POST['button'];
$autor= $_POST['autor'];
$tresc = $_POST['tekst'];
```

It should work properly now. Previously you were making a mistake that in the submit button field you were passing a php variable which could contain anything and you dont know if it is dynamic. So you weren't be able to get it by using $_REQUEST['id'] because it could have been some thing like this

```
$id = 1; or $id = 'dynamic string' ;
```